# Filter in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView witch initialized with data like this:

```
data class ObjectData(
    var name: String,
    var pass: Boolean
) : Serializable
```

I am Initialing the Adapter with ArrayList. In my Activity I have filter (All, Passed, No Passed). When I click one of the filters I wish that RecyclerView refresh with new data regarding the "pass" value. Example: On "Passed" filter button it will show only ObjectData with pass=true.

Question: What is the best approach to this? I can hold 3 list views, one with all data, one with passed objects and one with unpassed, and update adapter with the needed list when filter is changed. But this will cause data duplication. I can on filter copy all data to new filtered list, but it will trigger copy on every button filter click, and the user may change filters rapidly.

What can you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create copies lazily and cache them for example like this:

```
data class ObjectData(
    var name: String,
    var pass: Boolean
) : Serializable

val allData: List<ObjectData> = emptyList()

val filteredData: Map<Boolean, List<ObjectData>> by lazy {
    allData.groupBy { it.pass }
}
```

This way you'll create both filtered lists in one go and only when you need them.

Honestly if data set is not big i wouldn't really optimise prematurely unless i see performance is bad. Nowadays Android has much better memory handling.